# HTML space between td of a table

Tags: html

How is that possible that this work:

```
 <TABLE>
 <TR>
    <TD  onclick="play('cell1')" id="cell1">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell2')" id="cell2">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell3')" id="cell3">-</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell4')" id="cell4">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell5')" id="cell5">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell6')" id="cell6">-</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell7')" id="cell7">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell8')" id="cell8">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell9')" id="cell9">-</td>
 </TR>
```

but if I put spaces between "-" it doesn't. I knew that it doesn't matter in HTML the position of elements(I mean, in this case). Why?

Comment: You can use "&nbsp;" for space in HTML

Comment: your question is not clear if you want to remove the `-` and want to put the space so simply use `&nbsp` it will work.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What does "work" mean in this context? (And why are you using table data cell elements as buttons instead of button elements?)

Comment: @Quentin I believe the OP is asking why putting space between the dash symbol doesn't work.

Comment: Yes @Vucko, that was my question. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution:**

If I get it right, you want to put `-` between two spaces, so you will simply need to simulate this using `padding: 0px 5px;` with your `td` elements, this is a snippet DEMO:

```css
table td {
   padding: 0px 5px;
 }
```

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell1')" id="cell1">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell2')" id="cell2">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell3')" id="cell3">-</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell4')" id="cell4">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell5')" id="cell5">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell6')" id="cell6">-</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell7')" id="cell7">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell8')" id="cell8">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell9')" id="cell9">-</td>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

This will show `-` as `"  -  "` inside the `td` elements.

**HTML solution:**

If you want to use `HTML` only without `CSS`, the solution will be to use `cellpadding=5` with your `table`, this is a working snippet:

```html
<TABLE CELLPADDING=10>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell1')" id="cell1">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell2')" id="cell2">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell3')" id="cell3">-</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell4')" id="cell4">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell5')" id="cell5">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell6')" id="cell6">-</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="play('cell7')" id="cell7">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell8')" id="cell8">-</TD>
    <TD onclick="play('cell9')" id="cell9">-</td>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

But this will make spaces between `tr` elements too, in other words it will make `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` too for your `td` elements.

**Conclusion:**

So your requirements will be better achieved using `padding`in `CSS`, now it's up to you to choose the right solution.

Comment: @Vucko fair enough, but this will be the simpliest and the best solution.